# How to remove shipping options on the check out page? [Woocommerce]

Tags: php, html, css, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

How to remove shipping options on the check out page [screenshot below]? The order summary should include the shipping cost based on the settings on cart page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the "review-order.php" page and added a php code snippet in the table.

```
<?php $current_shipping_cost = WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total(); echo $current_shipping_cost;?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).